# How to refresh test database with production data periodically in Postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, database-administration, postgresql-9.5

Can you please tell me how to refresh test database with production data periodically in postgresql using ETL pipeline configuration? Is there any method other than ETL?

Answer (score 1):

ETL stands for “Extract, Transform, Load”, but you certainly won't need any transformations.

The typical way to copy a database to a test system is:

- Kill all connections to the target database.
- `DROP` the target database.
- `pg_dump` the source database.
- Restore the dump at the target.

The third and fourth step can be performed at the same time using a pipeline.

Comment: Without drop and restore any other options? I want to periodically refresh the test database. Is there any incremental method?

Comment: There is no incremental refresh unless you program it yourself. That would mean tracking additions and deletions.

Comment: That means we have to write some triggers?

Comment: I cannot think of a different way if you don't want to replace the whole database. But what if there are conflicts because something was changed on the copy?